# VS2017 opening .sln automatically opens same files

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I open my solution file with Visual Studio 2017 (ver 15.7.5) it always automatically opens the same 2 `.cs` files.  How can I prevent that?  Why does it opens those specific 2 files?

No they're not the last files I had opened last time I closed my solution.

Comment: Your work space settings are stored in the `.vs` folder in the root of your solution. Have you accidentally committed that folder to source control?

Comment: Thanks!  I deleted the .vs folder and fixed my problem!  :D  Please write is as an answer so I can give you credit for that! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All personal settings for a solution in Visual Studio 2017 are stored in a folder called `.vs` which is in the root of your repository. There's a couple of possibilities as to why your settings aren't changing:

1. The files have become corrupt and/or readonly for some reason. To fix this, just delete the folder. It's not crucial to anything and will get recreated automatically.
2. You have mistakenly committed the `.vs` folder to source control. Delete the folder from your source control and make sure it isn't readded by making sure that folder is ignored. A good way to do this with Git is to use [this](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) for your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Years later, still relevant. Had the same issue with VS2019 restoring 30+ files and 10+ breakpoints from an old debugging session every time I opened my solution. Super annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the `.vs` folder should help in this case. That's due to this folder containg file named `.dtbcache` which refernces files to be opened up.